# iphone like draggable images strip

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to find a jquery plugin to make the middle set of images slide like you're doing it in an iphone, you click and slide, I found one but it showed only one picture in a frame, so i made the width 100% and the animation started to go crazy as you can see in the link: http://theoikos.com/beta/

I got it from this site: http://jquery.hinablue.me/jqiphoneslide/

Any idea how to do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the effect you are looking for is "cover flow" (thats what apple calls it)

This looks like a pretty good aproximation http://www.jacksasylum.eu/ContentFlow/

EDIT: actually I suppose you just want a slider. The one you linked to is kind of crumby to begin with (that unnecesary bounce is terrible). Though I can't seem to find any better ones. May have to make something yourself. If I had a good excuse to, I'd make a plugin myself but I can't spent that kind of time on it. I'll see if I can find anything else.

EDIT2: Actually looking at it I think you can control the scaling on the content flow I posted so you can probably get it to do what you want without too much trouble.